# Quartz triggers scheduled miss fire

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I have encounter a issue in Quartz scheduler.

I have schedule a job(**MY_JOB**) run at every day 5 AM, for example it ran for Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday  and now I have shut down the scheduler for next 3 days(Thursday, Friday, and Saturday),and on Sunday I have restarted the scheduler at 2 AM. As soon as I restarted the scheduler at 2 AM(Not expected) MY_JOB is get queued and run , and again at 5 AM(Expected time of job run) is Queued and run .

So my question is about this behavior,

is that Quartz scheduler design like this if yes then why ?

And if it's not the correct behavior then what is remedy to fix this issue.

Any help will be much appreciated..

Comment: The next trigger time is already set in the `WRTZ_TRIGGERS` table. You need to update `misfire` instruction to `2` in the table. So it wouldn’t run the jobs that it missed.

Comment: Thanks @SunilDabburi for comment, I am just looking out for MISFIRE_INSTR 
 attribute value description, I am not able to get any, Could you please help us with some document where all this stuff described .

Comment: Check this article https://www.nurkiewicz.com/2012/04/quartz-scheduler-misfire-instructions.html and also SO